# Why might one server be able to browse nas by ip, ping by name but not browse by name?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-attached-storage, buffalo

Was in the process of some big copies from usb drive directly connected to nas and suddenly one of the servers could not connect to nas device by name but others can. Forcing in host file didn't help. What could cause this and anything that can be reset to resolve?

*UPDATE* - triggered failover to backup NAS and connection by (same) name was resolved, but still want to figure out what happened and why only this server was affected

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a WINS problem. Ping uses DNS, while CIFS uses WINS. Are both the NAS and the server in the same workgroup/domain?

Comment: WINS is not a communication protocol, just as DNS is not a communication protocol. WINS and DNS facilitate name resolution. You do not connect to CIFS/SMB shares using WINS or DNS. You probably meant NetBIOS rather than WINS. That being said, CIFS/SMB shares can be accessed by clients using either NetBIOS name resolution or DNS name resolution.

Comment: +1 as I got in the past a trouble like that but for Internet Explorer. nslookup gave the correct IP, but Internet Explorer was connecting to an old server. Deactivating wins resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

IPV6 has been known to cause some dns related issues, where you can/can't nslookup the host, browse by host, ping by host.

If this is a non-prod box, try disabling IPV6 on the NAS and your client host.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...

Can you access the resource using its fully-qualified name, e.g.:

```
net view \\mynas.mydomain.com
```

Assuming you're not already doing this, and this actually works, I'd be thinking along the lines of NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NBT) vs SMB.  When using the short name, it might be your server trying to access the NAS box via NBT (TCP 137), as opposed to SMB/CIFS (TCP 445).

If this is the case, disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP on the server (it shouldn't be needed these days).  This can be done under the WINS tab of your interface's IPv4 settings.